# Php sqlsrv - how use two or more databases

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to use two databases with one silver in the script, but the query does not work.
My connections:

```
$serverName = "12.354.25.5"; //serverName\instanceName
//first
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"GRQ", "UID"=>"RFUser", "PWD"=>"****", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
global $con;
$con = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
//second
$connectionpyr = array( "Database"=>"PiF", "UID"=>"greystone", "PWD"=>"****", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
global $conpyr;
$conpyr = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionpyr);
```

First connection is work fine, i use select by this and get data:

```
$SQL = "SELECT id,col1,col8,col9 FROM [dbo].[RF_TableWHERE ID=".$data[$k]."";
$result = sqlsrv_query($con,$SQL); //it work fine
```

Using the second connection, I try to execute a stored procedure,

```
$VER = "DECLARE @Debt MONEY, @ResultMsg NVARCHAR(255) 

        EXEC Pyramid.dbo.CheckDebt @AccountNumber =".$numlic.", -- int

    @PeriodFrom = '".$dstart."', -- date 

    @PeriodTo = '".$dend."', -- date 

    @Debt = @Debt OUTPUT, -- money

    @ResultMsg = @ResultMsg OUTPUT -- nvarchar(500)
    ";

$result2 = sqlsrv_query($conpyr,$VER);
```

but get only

> An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query.

Resource ID of connection two is empty (nothing)

How resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

If you have more than 1 database connections, you should close the connection1 before you start the connection to db2.